# How to make my php work from an external device?

Tags: php, iphone, wamp

I am really new at php and website development and I ran into an issue while trying to access my website from my smartphone.

I have installed wamp in my laptop and I have created a number of simple websites using php files. Each php file includes a button which calls another php and so on. I also have buttons that go back to the previous php. This works fine in my laptop

The problem is when I try to do the same using my iphone to access the website. I can load the website localhost\xxxxx.php and it works but when I click on the button that should redirect me to the next php website it does not load the next page and give me the message "The website is not available" ERR_ABORTED. However if I manually type the url of the php I am trying to access I have no problems.

I have my laptop and my iphone connected in the same wifi network.

This is my code

```
<form>

<strong>Base level <strong> <br>
<input type="button" value="Go to"  onClick="window.location.href='http://localhost/Base level.php '"><br>

Platform level <br>
 <input type="button" value="Go to" onClick="window.location.href='http://localhost/Platform level.php'"><br>

Cover level   <br>
<input type="button" value="Go to" onClick="window.location.href='http://localhost/Cover level.php'"><br>

xxxx level  <br>
<input type="button" value="Go to" onClick="window.location.href='http://localhost/xxxx level.php'"><br>

</form>
```

Most likely I am doing something wrong with my code and would appreciate if you could help me out a bit on this.

Thanks!

Jaime

Comment: try removing `http://localhost/` from the `onClick` attributes to use relative paths

Comment: Thanks @BobNocraz  I tried that but I still get the same error. Maybe it has something to do with the button definition I am using? The php still work on the laptop

Comment: I'm not quite sure how localhost on your laptop can be access from your phone.

Comment: I am using wamp to use my laptop as server and in my router I have redirected port 80 to my laptop. If I type my laptop's local IP in the iphone brower(either safari or chrome) I access localhost

Comment: ah, ok, so yea.  you don't want to use the location 'localhost' in your output then because it will try to use the phone's localhost.  You might try using the local IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: It worked now! It actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad its working now. Did any of the answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the location `localhost` will attempt to access a running web server on the device you are using (in this case, your iphone), it will not be able to access the PHP located on your remote server(well, your laptop).

My suggestion would be to change `localhost` in your HTML to the local/internal IP address of your laptop and maybe you will get better results.

example:

```
Cover level   <br>
<input type="button" value="Go to" onClick="window.location.href='http://INTERNALIPADDRESS/Cover level.php'"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna access you web site in you notebook from another device in same network you just need to use you IP address

Click in windows -> and write "cmd" -> press enter -> write:

```
ipconfig
```

press enter, it's will show your ip address.
then in you devide write you IP address in your browser URL:

```
https://youIPAddress/yourSite/index.php
```

Its will show you website in other device in same network.

Comment: Thanks Erasmo, that's the same advice than Bob Nocraz gave me and you both were right

Answer (score 0):

Don't use window.location it wont support in iphone.

just try location.href="'http://localhost/yourfilename.php '" .

it works on both.

Comment: Thanks @user3917020, I tried that and still same error. Should that work if I try on an android smartphone?

Comment: @JaimeGarrigos is type and go this url http://localhost/Base level.php in address bar works. Did you tried this onClick="location.href='http://localhost/Cover level.php'"

Comment: @JaimeGarrigos if stil not working i think javascript is disabled in your system .Enable java script on i phone , for detail check this link http://activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/ios

Comment: Unfortunately I check and the most relevant answer was the one by Bob Nocraz. I still appreciate your help, thanks